# Training weka models in matlab: how to evaluate? Mssing some model type?

Tags: matlab, weka

1. despite using weka I have models like libSVM and RseslibKnn, when I call them in Matlab it can't find them
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXJpB.png)
   and I noticed that actually they are not part of the models of the directories "classifiers".
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2vqK.png)
2. I know how to crossvalidate a generic model but I can't use the simple validation with determinated training and test set. Here the code I'm using:

% memorize current folder and change folder

base_folder = cd;

cd 'C:\Program Files'

% adding weka in the java folder

javaaddpath("weka-3-8-4/weka.jar");

% loading arff training set

l = javaObject("weka.core.converters.ArffLoader");

l.setFile(javaObject("java.io.File","weka-3-8-4/data/weka_BEST_train_ESS.arff"));

tr = l.getDataSet;

tr.toString;

% building classfiers

c = javaObject("weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron");

tr.setClassIndex(tr.numAttributes - 1);

c.buildClassifier(tr);

c.toString;

% loading arff test set

l = javaObject("weka.core.converters.ArffLoader");

l.setFile(javaObject("java.io.File","weka-3-8-4/data/weka_BEST_test_ESS.arff"));

ts = l.getDataSet;

ts.toString;

% validation

e = javaObject("weka.classifiers.Evaluation", tr);

e.evaluateModel(c, ts); %?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????

e.toSummaryString;

% going back to the current folder

cd (base_folder)

Answer (score 0):

Answering to the first question:

libSVM and RseslibKnn are models available in separate Weka packages that need to be additionally installed in Weka. To install the packages run Weka package manager (menu Tools -> Package Manager in Weka GUI Chooser) and install LibSVM and Rseslib packages. The packages with their java jars are installed in the wekafiles directory. On Windows it is `C:\Users\ <username>\wekafiles\packages` by default.

I don't know Matlab but I guess that to use models from extra Weka packages you need to add also the package jar files to Matlab javapath after installing the packages in Weka:

javaaddpath("C:\Users\ <username>\wekafiles\packages\Rseslib\rseslib.jar");

javaaddpath("C:\Users\ <username>\wekafiles\packages\LibSVM\LibSVM.jar");

Alternatively, you can download the libraries directly from the web sites of the package providers, unpack them and add jars to Matlab javapath:

http://rseslib.mimuw.edu.pl/download.html

[https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/)

Comment: It worked!! At least one problem is solved, thanks a milion!!!